# "Our system has identified this post as possible spam" message shown twice

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts

Another non-critical bug, but I've long since noticed that when you are reviewing a low-quality answer (I'm pretty sure I've noticed it on multiple stacks) which the system has identified as possible spam, a "Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully" message shows up *not only over the answer* but also over the question which is shown below for reference.

A picture is worth a thousand words (screenshot from a review on Ask Ubuntu):

[image: Screenshot of review audit]

In this particular case it was a review audit, but I'm fairly certain I've seen the same bug elsewhere - and if I haven't, it's kind of a dead give away for review audits which ought to be removed.

Comment: Both posts can be flagged as spam so why this is a bug?

Comment: @rene,  Both *can*, but I happen to know that the question was not.

Comment: I'm not sure what the bug is. Is it because *it's kind of a dead give away for review audits*? If so, then this is status-bydesign.

Comment: @rene, no, it's that it shows "Our system has identified this post as ..." over the *question*, which the system has obviously not identified as spam: it's a three year old post that's still around.

Comment: This can also occur with only the question showing the warning: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O4HZ.png); [review](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/313173). You can edit this into your question...